# Is there a formula for the $i$th Chow group $CH_i(X\times\mathbb{P}^n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a formula for the $i$th Chow group $CH_i(X\times\mathbb{P}^n)$ for a variety $X$? I heard there was a formula in one of Fulton's texts, but I've been scouring them and can't find one.

Comment: Look for "Projective bundle formula" in Fulton's _Intersection Theory_.